# In IBM RAD WebSphere, which file describes WebSphere variables of administration control?

Tags: java, console, websphere, administration, rad

I am using the IBM RAD WebSphere to deploy a project.

Recently I have changed the "JAVA HOME" of "WebSphere variable" in the Administration Console. And then the server can't start. So I can no longer go to the Administration Control to change the variable value back. Is there anyone who knows which file I can search to change this value back so that I can start the server, please?

Answer (score 2):

WebSphere variables are stored in the variables.xml file which resides in the profile directory for the affected server.  For more info, see this WebSphere KnowledgeCenter [topic](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/ucws_rvars.html?lang=en).  By default, **JAVA_HOME** is defined at node scope with the value of ${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/java, so it is defined in the **${USER_INSTALL_ROOT}/config/cells/cell_name/nodes/node_name/variables.xml** file.

Comment: You found it and were able to fix the problem?

Comment: After apply your changes, I no longer see the error. But I see another error under Console:
Unrecognized option: -Xshareclasses:name=webspherev85_1.6_64,nonFatal
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: What exactly did you change?